# @Keyframs move { SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in using react-block-reveal-animation React + Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using [React-Block-Reveal-Animation](https://github.com/pettersamuelsen/react-block-reveal-animation) in React + Next.js project. It is working fine in only React project but gives this error in React + Next.

```
Invalid or unexpected token
E:\Projects\nextjs\Website\node_modules\react-block-reveal-animation\dist\BlockRevealAnimation.css:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { @keyframes move {
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Projects\nextjs\Website\node_modules\react-block-reveal-animation\dist\BlockRevealAnimation.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoa`enter code here`d (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
```

```html
import React from 'react';
import BlockRevealAnimation from 'react-block-reveal-animation';
const BlockAnimation = () => (
    <div id="rev-6 Tilt-inner" >
          <BlockRevealANimation>
             <img src="static/images/dew-ban.jpg" alt="dew-ban" data-tilt />
          </BlockRevealANimation>
     </div>
)
export default BlockAnimation
```

[Complete error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZjps.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like next trying to import and use the .css file from the "react-block-reveal-animation" module.

I guess you didnt implemented css processor in the next.config.js

like this:

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')

module.exports = compose([[withCSS]])
```

you can have better explanation [here](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css)

Comment: Yes i have used [next-css](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css). and also added this too.
`// next.config.js
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS()`

Comment: try to import css file in the same js file and see if it doesnt throw an error

Comment: css comes from node_modules file at run time.